# remove repeated records only for some rows with dplyr

Tags: dplyr, duplicates, subset

I'd like to remove records repeated twice or more times (based on variables: `ID`, `start`, `drug`), but only for some rows. What am I writing wrong?

```
data <- data %>%
          case_when(ID %in% c(282,464,474)) %>%
          distinct(ID, start, drug, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Take a look at the case_when grammar, it is not supposed to work like that. It evaluates a condition a returns a value if the condition is TRUE. For instance, `case_when(a > b, ~ "a is biguer than b")`.

Comment: In addition, it's hard to help you without more detail about what you want to do. May you want to remove duplicates only in those ids or everywhere except those id? A small reprex would be ideal to tackle your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Could you suggest a correct alternative to case_when to remove duplicates for those rows only?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I want to remove duplicates ONLY in those ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subset data, remove duplicates and join again.

```
data <- data %>%
          filter(ID %in% c(282,464,474)) %>%
          distinct(ID, start, drug, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
bind_rows(data %>% 
    filter(!(ID %in% c(282,464,474))))
```